# How to transpose columns to rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I'm trying to take a raw data set that adds columns for new data and convert it to a more traditional table structure. The idea is to have the script pull the column name (the date) and put that into a new column and then stack each dates data values on top of each other.

Example

```
Store     1/1/2013     2/1/2013
XYZ INC   $1000        $2000
```

To

```
Store     Date         Value
XYZ INC   1/1/2013     $1000
XYZ INC   2/1/2013     $2000
```

thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking, it looks simple.  If you can show us how the data is stored now (table defs) or show us what you already have, we can show you how to get there.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different ways that you can get the result that you want.

You can use a `SELECT` with `UNION ALL`:

```
select store, '1/1/2013' date, [1/1/2013] value
from yourtable
union all
select store, '2/1/2013' date, [2/1/2013] value
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbe7c/1).

You can use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select store, date, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for date in ([1/1/2013], [2/1/2013])
) un;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbe7c/2).

Finally, depending on your version of SQL Server you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select store, date, value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
    ('1/1/2013', [1/1/2013]),
    ('2/1/2013', [2/1/2013])
) c (date, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbe7c/3). All versions will give a result of:

```
|   STORE |     DATE | VALUE |
|---------|----------|-------|
| XYZ INC | 1/1/2013 |  1000 |
| XYZ INC | 2/1/2013 |  2000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the details of the problem (i.e. source format, number and variability of dates, how often you need to perform the task, etc), it very well may be much easier to use some other language to parse the data and perform either a reformatting function or the direct insert into the final table.

The above said, if you're interested in a completely SQL solution, it sounds like you're looking for some dynamic pivot functionality.  The keywords being `dynamic SQL` and `unpivot`.  The details vary based on what RDBMS you're using and exactly what the specs are on the initial data set.

Comment: It is very rare that a pivot or un-pivot would need to be dynamic and there is nothing to suggest a dynamic solution is needed from the question.

Comment: @Hogan, you're correct, there is very little detail provided in this question.  However, I completely disagree with your assessment that it's rare for a pivot/unpivot to be dynamic.  While it might not be needed here, there is a very clear indication that the columns being unpivoted change somewhat frequently.  So, unless you like constantly revisiting the code you write, a little dynamic SQL can solve this problem neatly.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a scripting language (Perl, Python, etc.) to generate an INSERT statement for each date column you have in the original data and transpose it into a row keyed by `Store` and `Date`.  Then run the inserts into your normalized table.

Comment: This makes no sense, why use a scripting language when the pivot can be done in SQL?