# Transpose table with columns (sql)

Tags: sql, transpose

I have a table t1 with two columns c1 (int) and c2 (nvarchar). In this table always only one row.
For example, query `select c1,c2 from t1` returns result set:

```
c1   c2
---- ----
1    a
```

And I need transpose table with columns, so I excpect this result:

```
col name  value
--------  -----
c1        1
c2        a
```

I have now idea, how to write this query. Hope you can help me.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose columns to rows in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956594/how-to-transpose-columns-to-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work for all databases:

```
SELECT 'C1' As ColName,
        c1  As ColValue
FROM Table

UNION

SELECT 'C2',
        c2
FROM Table
```